# How can I remove a large document library from SharePoint but save it on my computer first?

Tags: sharepoint, download, document

Our company has a very large document library that is taking up an enormous amount of our allocated space.  I want to delete the library but not before backing it up onto my harddrive, first.  Can you help?  I found directions that instruct to use Outlook, but I don't want put this library in Outlook.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

You could open up the library in Explorer View, then simply select all files and copy to a local folder.

Comment: Explorer View isn't working on Windows 7.  I get an error message.

Comment: Explorer View does normally work with Windows 7. What is the error message your getting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to be able to search for those files in SharePoint after you remove them from it? If yes, then you will need to move the files to a network share and configure the crawler to scan the files there. Alternatively, you could create a records center site collection in SharePoint and move the files that you don't need any more from your working site to the record's center. That way they will stay in SharePoint, but would not occupy quota in your production sites (but would still occupy SharePoint space somewhere, so this might not be an option if you absolutely need to trim down the SharePoint space).

Comment: No.  I just need to take them off but want to back them up, first.